# Should the undelete via Apex behave the same way as Recycle bin undelete

Tags: apex, account, bulk-delete

Does the undelete via Apex behave the same way as Recycle bin undelete?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_undelete.htm):

> The undelete DML operation restores one or more existing sObject
>   records, such as individual accounts or contacts, from your
>   organization’s Recycle Bin. undelete is analogous to the UNDELETE
>   statement in SQL.

It is undeleting it from the Recycle Bin, so yes, I would say it should behave the same way.

Comment: For the sake of pointing it out, and based solely on my experience with DataLoader... I believe you ARE limited on how many records end up IN the recycle bin when bulk deleting(?).  DataLoader seems to warn you about this when deleting a few thousand.  Someone more knowledgeable than I should verify/clarify.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Went into panic as some accounts got deleted by accident. In the end I went one by one through the recycle bin instead of running some apex like this List<Contact> c = [select Id from Contact where IsDeleted = true limit 1000]; undelete c;